# Low resolution device compatibility

Tags: android

I have done small application for android, when I execute the application in high resolution emulator(such as HVGA) it looks fine, I tried the same thing in my android mobile, in which I saw the pixels of the widgets are breaking at the edges, then I created one emulator using QVGA same  thing happens in my emulator too, it looks like

[image]

I can't find a solution for this, any help, I'm using Android 2.2 API 8, and mobile version is 2.2.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Define all your sizes in Density Independent Pixels (`dip`s) so that your sizes scale properly with resolution changes
- Create different versions of your images so that Android does not have to scale them itself and place them in the `drawable-ldpi` (QVGA), `drawable-mdpi` (HVGA) and `drawable-hdpi` (WVGA+) folders.
- Take a look at [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- Define different layouts for smaller devices when necessary

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yeah I've given everything in 'dp' only.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I suggest using 9-patch images. They scale perfectly without any issues.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

I just used 'dp' values for every property, and I've given a line

supports-screens anyDensity="true"

in AndroidManifest.xml and now its looking good.
Thanks Joseph Earl for the link.